# Prevent overriding protocol method implemented in extension in Swift

Tags: swift, struct, protocols

I am using structs to move around a specific data format linking a some text and a color. The reason I keep these coupled in a struct rather than touple is that I need to have 2 functions that convert between the struct and a dictionary so that I can save it.

The thing is that I use this structure in many areas and to keep proper naming, I have multiple of such structs which have exactly the same implementation, just a different name. Currently that behaviour is defined in a protocol, but each individual struct can override it. Is there any way to forbid this?

For example, the `TitleColorStructProtocol` has an extension with this function

```
init(dictionary: Dictionary<String, Any>) {
    self.init()

    self.title = dictionary["title"] as! String

    if let red = dictionary["red"], let green = dictionary["green"], let blue = dictionary["blue"] {
        self.color = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: red as! Float, green: green as! Float, blue: blue as! Float, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

There is no reason why any struct conforming this protocol should override this method so I would like to "lock" it, use something like the `final` keyword for classes. Is this possible?

Comment: You cannot prevent a type from implementing a protocol method. But it may help that extension methods which are *not* defined as a protocol requirement are statically dispatched: https://oleb.net/blog/2016/06/kevin-ballard-swift-dispatch/.